# Adding Constraint messed up view

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, constraints, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a view with a `UICollectionView` and a `UISegmentedControl`.

I want to change constraints so the segment controller won't overlap collection view, like in this picture:

[image]

This is my code :

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true


        self.SegmentController.setTitle(SegmentAtext, forSegmentAt: 0)
        self.SegmentController.setTitle(SegmentBtext, forSegmentAt: 1)


        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: SegmentController)

        self.LoadProducts(productsToShow: SegmentAtype)
    }
```

SO I add this command:

```
self.ProductsCollection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SegmentController.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
```

But the result is worse:

[image]

Now the segment controller is almost completely hidden!

How do I fix this?

Edit:

My viewDidLayoutSubviews function:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        ProductsCollection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductsCollection, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductsCollection, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -50) //leaving space for search field
        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductsCollection, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductsCollection, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        self.view.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint])
    }
```

Notice:

my `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is implemented in the super view, which does not contain a `UISegmentedControl`. the `UISegmentedControl` is contained in an inheriting view.

Edit: An updated view

[image]

Comment: What is the desired outcome?

Comment: I want the CollectionView to be below the SegmentControl

Comment: @Ladislav see my answer :)

Comment: What is a `SegmentController`? Do you mean `UISegmentedControl` or?

Comment: Also paste the code of how you are currently laying out `UICollectionView` then I can help

Comment: I hope I added enough info to the post :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would want the `UISegmentedControl` to be centred on the screen and below it to have your collection view you would do

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    segmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.bottomAnchor),
    collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
    collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
```

So we have segmented controls top be top of the view, and center it, 
then top of collection view is bottom of segmented control (you can add a constant for padding if needed) and left right and bottom to the view

Comment: Did you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` for both?

Comment: Oh wait. I forgot to mention I have a nav controller up top, so I guess it's hidden behind it ?

Comment: Or you can try fixing the first constraint with `segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)`

Comment: I added an image of my entire view :)

Comment: Try replacing the constraint i mentioned in comment above

Comment: Trying this now. Didn't you mean segmentedControl's top anchor should equial to Safe area's bottom one ?

Comment: Segment Controller is still hidden behind "Seach for tools and resources" search bar

Comment: SegmentController.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 10) --- this didn't change anything :(

Comment: Try at least 64 or 100 just to see it move to the screen

Comment: And dont use `safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor`, but `topAnchor`

Comment: Still nothing...

This line : SegmentController.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100),

Comment: Did you delete constrains from `func viewDidLayoutSubviews()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179188/discussion-between-ladislav-and-ofri).

Comment: I didn't delete the function. I'm waiting in chat