# UICollectionViewCell duplication

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, duplicates

I know this was asked here before already, but my issue is a bit different, and following this guide didn't help:

[CollectionView duplicate cell when loading more data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674788/collectionview-duplicate-cell-when-loading-more-data)

So my situation is:

1. I'm on ProductPageView - Deleting Product
2. Product removed from Database (Successfully)
3. Unwind Segue fires up
4. In callback, I remove the deleted product from collection
5. I refresh collection
6. View loads up with duplicate cell

**Beginning of my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` :**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "product_collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! ProductsCollectionViewCell
    cell.ProductImageView.image = nil
    cell.ProductName.text = nil
    cell.ProductPrice.text = nil
    cell.productUniqueID = nil

    let prodInCell =  searchActive ? filtered[indexPath.row] : products[indexPath.row]

    let prodID = prodInCell.getUniqueID()
    let dbRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(prodID).child("pic0.jpg")
    cell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    cell.ProductImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DefaultProductImage")
    dbRef.downloadURL(completion:
        {
            url, error in
            if let error = error
            {
                print (error)
            }
            else if let url = url
            {
                cell.ProductImageView.loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: url.absoluteString)
                cell.ProductImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
                cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
    })
    cell.ProductImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    //cell.ProductName = UILabel()
    cell.ProductName.text = prodInCell.getName()

    //cell.ProductPrice = UILabel()
    cell.ProductPrice.text = String(prodInCell.getPrice())
    cell.productUniqueID = prodInCell.getUniqueID()
    return cell
}
```

My unwind callback function:

```
@IBAction func unwindFromDeleteSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
    if (prodToLoad == nil) {return}

    for product in products
    {
        if product.getUniqueID() == prodToLoad?.getUniqueID()
        {
            products.remove(at: products.index(of: product)!)
            ProductsCollection.reloadData()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

My  `numberOfItemsInSection` :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if searchActive
        {
            return filtered.count
        }
        else
        {
            return products.count    //return number of rows in section
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please point me out to where the source of my bug might be  ?

**Notice:**

This doesn't occur only when loading more data, it also occurs when there is only 1 item in collection, and cells are not being reused

EDIT:

I noticed that when this line is in comment:

```
StaticFunctions.ProductsStaticFunctions.removeProductFromDatabase(productUniqueID: self.productToDisplay.getUniqueID(), ownerID: self.productToDisplay.getOwnerID())
```

It works fine. When I un-comment it, it stops working properly again.

```
public static func removeProductFromDatabase(productUniqueID: String, ownerID: String)
        {

        let childUpdates = ["/\(Constants.TREE_A)/\(ownerID)/\(productUniqueID)/" : nil,
                            "/\(Constants.TREE_B)/\(ownerID)/\(productUniqueID)/" : nil,
                            "/\(Constants.TREE_C)/\(productUniqueID)/" : nil,
                            "/\(Constants.TREE_D)/\(productUniqueID)/" : nil,
                            "/\(Constants.TREE_E)/\(ownerID)/\(productUniqueID)/": nil,
                            "/\(Constants.TREE_F)/\(ownerID)/\(productUniqueID)/": nil,
                            "/\(Constants.TREE_G)/\(productUniqueID)/" : nil,
                            "/\(Constants.TREE_H/\(productUniqueID)/" : nil
            ] as [String : Any?]

        Constants.refs.databaseRoot.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
    }
```

My method for adding product to array:

```
ref?.observe(.value, with:
            { (snapshot) in

            let allChildrenObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects
            if allChildrenObjects.count == 0 {self.StopLoadingAnimation() ; return}

            for child in allChildrenObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            {
                // Code to execute when new product is added
                let prodValueDictionary = child.value as? NSDictionary

                if ((currentUserId == prodValueDictionary?[Constants.Products.ProductFields.PRODUCT_OWNER_ID] as? String) == itemsOfCurrentUser)
                {
                    self.AddProductToCollection(productAsDictionary: prodValueDictionary, IsProductMine: itemsOfCurrentUser)
                    self.DispatchQueueFunc()
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you add `numberOfItemsInSection` code

Comment: When you are doing `ProductsCollection.reloadData()` then you don't need to do `ProductsCollection.deleteItems(at: [indexPath!])`. It will help us if you can share more code from `cellForItemAt` and `numberOfItemsInSection`.

Comment: Added the required functions :)

Comment: @PratikPrajapati Do you know how to continue ?

Comment: @Ofri i think problem is in loading, check your data array after delete, its possible that your array contain duplicates, if you refreshing you array then first remove all data from array.

Comment: Hey, checked it and my data array does not contain duplicates...

Comment: I updated my unwind function

Comment: print the count of the array before and after the delete , also check that you remove from the filtered array also

Comment: After Deletion, Filtered is empty, the products collection holds only 1 products - as it should...

Comment: Ok, I found out something weird.

It worked properly when I commented out this command:

StaticFunctions.ProductsStaticFunctions.removeProductFromDatabase(productUniqueID: self.productToDisplay.getUniqueID(), ownerID: self.productToDisplay.getOwnerID())


And when I re-added it, it stopped working properly again. I am editing question

Comment: Edited question @Sh_Khan

Comment: can you show me how you fill the array originally

Comment: Added to bottom of post

Comment: I mean the observe block  to firebase that you call that method from ?

Comment: I edited again :)

Comment: @Sh_Khan I added the piece of code you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use

```
ref?.observe(.value, with:
        { (snapshot) in
```

you'll be in threat that this callback is called every edit that occurs to it , which leads to an unexpected results as you encounter like duplicating data inside the array , so you need a single observe

```
ref?.observeSingleEvent(.value, with:
        { (snapshot) in
```

Comment: You are the best

Comment: I have one more unanswered question if you'd be so kind as to take a look :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112425/adding-constraint-messed-up-view/52116082?noredirect=1#comment91184964_52116082